# Android Properties DIRECT xml file changes/editing

Tags: android, xml, file, preferences, editing

I have a Properties Activity where the user has to provide some data to conect to the server and update some data.

```
public class Preferencias extends PreferenceActivity {


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);

    setContentView(R.layout.preferences);


}
```

Would it be possible to edit the properties file manually (so NOT through the activity or

```
  SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManage.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context)) ?
```

Something like ....

```
FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(/data/data/com.your.package, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

so that the user can open the xml file and can edit it? 
(This is posible in other platforms that's why I am asking)

thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use internal storage as files there won't be accessible to user(or by any other application).

However you can create the xml file in [***external storage***](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal) so that user can access it. Then once the modifications are done you can load it.

Comment: thanks but can this file then replace the Default shared Preferences?